# Average Record Count Per Month Report

Tags: formula, reporting, dashboard, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I am looking to create a column on a report that shows the average record count per month. I am unable to add a row level formula to this report. The blacked out parts on the image represent the opportunity owner. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. What part of adding a report formula is not working? Also I think Summary formulas will be a better option than row-level as you are not showing detail rows on this report.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm unsure what summary formula to use here?